# Ambiguous match using nth-child capybara

Tags: html, capybara

I am trying to test that sorting works on an app I am testing. I have added 2 entries 'a' and 'b'. I wish to test that a appear before b. Html is as follows:

```
<ul id="attendee-list" class="bars">
<div>
    <li id="attendee-812202" class="bar border link attendee">
    <a class="expandable clearfix" href="#!/person/812202/">
</div>
     <div class="description">
     <p class="title">a</p>
     <p class="subtitle"></p>
     <p class="subtitle"></p>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</div>
<div>
     <li id="attendee-812206" class="bar border link attendee">
     <a class="expandable clearfix" href="#!/person/812206/">
     <div class="description">
     <p class="title">b</p>
<p class="subtitle"></p>
<p class="subtitle"></p>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

So what I have tried is the following:

```
  find("ul.bars li:nth-child(1) a div.description p.title").should have_content("a")
  find("ul.bars li:nth-child(2) a div.description p.title").should have_content("b")
```

However I get an ambiguous match error. Does anyone know if I am doing anything wrong here or perhaps an alternative method to verify?

Comment: I advice you to save this HTML into file, open it in Chrome and debug your css selectors [using $$](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1). I think it will be a better help for you than to direct answer.

Comment: Ehm, that HTML you've got there, is that how it actually appears in the source, or, ehm, is it only used as input for Capybara or something?

Comment: This is how the html appears in the source. The indentations may be different, when I copied it into stack overflow it just appeared as normal text so I tried to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: @user1523236 Sorry, but the indentation, while bad, is not the worst thing about this HTML.

Comment: @Mr Lister - Yep, agreed. We are in the middle of a site redeisgn at the company I work for and I have been assured that in the new super amazing build, all the html will be perfect. I aint holding my breath! :-) Until then, I have to work around what's there.

Comment: @Andrey Botalov  - Thanks Andrey, I will have a look at your suggestion and see if I can come up with an alternative method.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem is the `li:nth-child(1)`. This says to find an `li` that is the first child of its parent. Since each `li` is wrapped in a `div`, both `li` elements are first children - ie both of the titles are returned by selector `ul.bars li:nth-child(1) a div.description p.title` (hence the ambiguous match).

**Solution 1 - Find All**

I think the easiest solution is to use the css-selector to return all titles and then use Capybara to check the first and second ones.

```
# Get all titles
titles = page.all("ul.bars li a div.description p.title")

# Make sure that the first and second have the correct content
titles[0].should have_content("a")
titles[1].should have_content("b")
```

**Solution 2 - Xpath**

An alternative solution, if you do not want to get all (perhaps there are too many on the page), is to try xpath. It is not very pretty, but you can do:

```
page.find(:xpath, '(//ul[@class="bars"]/div/li/a/div[@class="description"]/p[@class="title"])[1]').should have_content("a")
page.find(:xpath, '(//ul[@class="bars"]/div/li/a/div[@class="description"]/p[@class="title"])[2]').should have_content("b")
```

Comment: Thanks Justin!! The first answer you supplied was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed explanation also!!

Comment: Warning: capybara's all method doesn't wait for elements to load. If you need an nth-child of dynamic content you must use find with xpath

Comment: @nolanpro, you could use the `:minimum` option if you need to wait for a certain amount. For example `page.all("ul.bars li a div.description p.title", minimum: 4)` will wait for at least 4 elements to be available.